# Reading bits from the bin value

Tags: c++, c, memory, bit

What is the order one has to read the bits from the bin value? Having for e.g. [this official MS doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/inputdev/wm-char) site regarding the `lParam` of the `WM_CHAR` message, they explain what bits have what meaning. Taking the bits *16-23* for the *scan code* value should I read the bits from right to left or vice versa?

Comment: What does this have to do with assembly?

Comment: Is your question regarding WM_CHAR specifically or any chunk of binary data? Because that's two entirely different questions. In Winapi programming you'd use `HIWORD` and `LOWORD` macros on `lParam` etc without much care of the underlying binary representation. Hence API.

Comment: This _is_ a duplicate, but I'm voting to reopen, because of @TedLyngmo explanation, which is so much clearer. Also, this question is worded much better. I'd prefer the other question closed as a duplicate pointing to this one.

Comment: I could not vote to close the other one because cycles not allowed, but guys, I'd swap them any time!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The page you linked to uses [LSB 0 bit numbering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bit_numbering#LSB_0_bit_numbering) so you can extract bits 16-23 with

```
lParam & 0b00000000111111110000000000000000U
//         |       |      |               |
// bit    31      23     16               0
//        MSB                            LSB
```

Note: The `0b` prefix for binary numbers requires C++14. In C it's only available as an extension in some implementations.

You may also want to shift down the result with

```
(lParam & 0b00000000111111110000000000000000U) >> 16U
```

or simpler

```
(lParam >> 16U) & 0b11111111U //  or  (lParam >> 16U) & 0xFFU
```

Comment: Thx. So the bits is indexed from right to left order and when they say for e.g. bit _#3_ for say `0b0000'0101` value - its the second `"1"` from the right side?

Comment: @DarosRT10 You're welcome. It uses [LSB 0 bit numbering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bit_numbering) so, bit0 is the first `1` and bit2 is the second `1` from the right side.

Comment: note C++14 or newer or gcc family compiler needed. In C 0b notation is the gcc extension

Comment: @P__J__ Indeed. I didn't think about mentioning that. Modern Visual Studio versions default to C++14. Added note. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

two ways:

```
UINT bitsxtractBits(UINT val, int startBit, int nbits)
{
    UINT mask = ((UINT)1 << nbits) - 1;

    return (val & mask) >> startBit;
}

//note it will not work if you want to extract all bits (in this case 32). 
//but in this case you do not need to extract them :)
```

and the usage to extract your bits:

```
bitsxtractBits(message, 16, 8)
```

or

```
union WM_CHAR_message
{
    struct 
    {
        UINT    repatCount : 16;
        UINT    scanCode   : 8;
        UINT    : 4;
        UINT    contextCode : 1;
        UINT    previousState : 1;
        UINT    transitionState : 1;
    };
    UINT  raw;
};

LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hwnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    union WM_CHAR_message msgu;
    //C++ safe
    memcpy(&msgu, &message, sizeof(msgu));  // will be optimized to the store instruction only
    switch (message)
    {
   
    // ...

    case WM_CHAR:
        switch(msgu.scanCode)
        {
            //....
        }
        OnKeyPress(wParam);
        break;

    default:
        return DefWindowProc(hwnd, message, wParam, lParam);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Note: In C++ it's undefined behavior writing to one union member and then reading from another and anonymous structs are forbidden. Designated initializers only works in C++20 and later.

Comment: @TedLyngmo indeed - amended